# How to detect if a user entered a number larger than 4294967295 in MIPS?

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

I thought I could check if there's an overflow, but not sure what register will hold a flag. I need to inform the user that the value is too large and to insert again.

I have this code :

```
        .data

binBuffer: .space 20


        .text
main:

        addu $t0, $t0, 4294967298
    
        li $v0, 36
        move $a0, $t0
        syscall
```

But when I print it, it shows the number 2, however, I thought I could compare the original number with 2 but then I couldn't even store that large number.

Any thoughts how to inform the user if the number is too large?

The above code is just a minimum application, what I'm doing is taking the user input from console as decimal strings, and then convert them into hex and binary. and also the decimal taken from the user is stored into a string and then is also converted into a decimal number with base 10

Comment: MIPS registers cannot hold numbers larger than that, so the question is ill-posed.

Comment: @fuz I fixed the question

Comment: If you don't have a carry flag, the easiest way to detect overflow on addition is to check if the sum is smaller than one of the summands.  This happens if and only if the sum overflowed the register.

Comment: The immediate for `addiu` is 16-bit sign-extended.  If the assembler doesn't treat this as an error, most will just truncate.  (MARS may treat that as an "extended pseudo-instruction" and allow a full 32-bit integer immediate, which it materializes into `$at` with the equivalent of `li`, but it's still just truncation.)

Comment: When you talk about a "user", do you mean "programmer", or did you actually want to ask about a program that reads a number as a string of base-10 digits on the console or as a command-line arg?  In that case you can read into a buffer and do string-to-int conversion yourself with overflow checking in the `total = total*10 + digit` steps.  In the case you've shown, the asm text has already been converted to binary machine code before your program starts running, and it doesn't have access to is source code.

Comment: @PeterCordes not the programmer, but another user of my program. in Hex it's very easy to check if there's larger than FFFFFFFF, I just  converted them to string and counted if they are 8 and since they're all F, I don't need to check any other possibilities. But in integer, if it was 9999999999 then it would be easier, but it isn't, the user can still input 10 digit like this 5294967298 and it shouldn't accept.

Comment: @harold I updated my post, imagine I took a string input of 99999999999999, then the algorithm I wrote will take the length of the string and that would be the power of the base 10, but how can i check for overflow?

Comment: If you already have a number in a register, it's too late.  You have to check the user's input **string** before converting it, because math operations on registers wrap at 32-bit boundaries.  Converting that truncated number back to a string will always give you a number between 0 and 2^32-1

Comment: Rather than checking the string itself (which is possible too) I think we can get away with detecting overflow during the conversion, checking both the "multiply by 10" step and the "add to total" step for unsigned overflow.

Comment: @harold how to check for unsigned overflow?

Comment: For addition that's easy, check if the sum is unsigned less than one of the inputs (pick either of them, doesn't matter). For the multiplication by 10, it depends on how you perform it, if you use `multu` then you can `mfhi` and check whether the high part is non-zero.

Comment: @harold: A couple years ago I tried optimizing int parsing to only check based on length and stuff after encountering a non-digit, not inside the loop.  I was going to improve glibc, but without a good portable C way to do `std::numeric_limits<int>::digits10` and get the leading decimal digit of INT_MAX as a compile-time constant, I ran out of ideas and never got back to it.  https://godbolt.org/z/YKGMxKbE6 is my work-in-progress.  IIRC, it should be much faster for the common case of no overflow especially for 32-bit ints less than 9 digits long.  Leading zeros were also an obstacle.

Comment: There's no way to do this with MARS/QtSpim syscalls alone.  You need to convert characters to numeric values, while detecting overflow.  This means this is not a MIPS problem but an algorithmic problem.  Any language can detect overflow while converting bytes in a string to numeric value , so research on that.  You'll  need a proper algorithm and then a implementation in MIPS. It is true that some instruction sets make detecting overflow easier but MIPS is not one, so have to do the same as C, which also doesn't offer direct overflow checking.

Answer (score 2):

Detecting a string that represents an integer to see if it fits in 32 bits is not a MIPS specific problem.

Here are sone basic approches.

- Do string compare for max values.
- Use extended precision arithmetic, such as 64 bit arithmetic.  With that, check for either too many digits (e.g. 12), or a 64-bit number that doesn't fit in 32-bits.
- Check for overflow in all arithmetic operations, here ×10, and addition.  Since these are such simple operations, can check for overflow before the operation!  For example in 8 bits unsigned, 25 × 10 will not overflow (250), but 26 × 10 will (260), so can check for > 25 before multiplying,   Otherwise, if easy (i.e x86) check after.